# JDBC connection to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL is failing

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I am trying to connect Cloud SQL Postgres using JDBC Using SSL without Certificate Validation.

The option I passed to the JDBC connection is "?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"

The connection fails with the below error:

> [Permission denied] PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid
> client certificate

It seems the connect string options "sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory" is not considered.

Can you please advise how to connect SSL Cloud SQL PostgreSQL without validating SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The server is demanding a *client* certificate to prove the identity of the client.  This is an unusual setting, but if that is how the server is configured (via pg_hba.conf) you can't make it change its mind from the client side, other than perhaps switching to a connection method that matches a different pg_hba.conf line.  But of course you can't do that unless another suitable pg_hba.conf entry exists, which is not under the client's control.

Talk to whoever is in charge of the server about either changing the configuration, or granting you a client cert.

There is no such thing as a non-validating client cert.  It would be pointless: if you don't want to validate the client cert you just wouldn't demand one.  If you just want encryption without validation, then the usual server cert (without validation) is entirely sufficient to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76894715/6514559