# connection requires a valid client certificate in laravel google cloud postgres with ssl mode

Tags: laravel, postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am facing a issue when trying to connect to gcloud postgres db allowing ssl in my laravel application which is running in the cloud run. I downloaded all three cert files from gcloud and set the path in config/database.php.

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'require',
            'options' => [
               'sslcert' => storage_path(path: 'client-cert.pem'),
               'sslkey' => storage_path(path: 'client-key.pem'),
               'sslrootcert' => storage_path(path: 'server-ca.pem'),
            ],
        ],
```

After enabling the 'Allow only SSL connections' I am getting this error:

`'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate (SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = wDJOd7Ssm6ggLngYQPprlIP0FNrtMxGTtCW4lELX limit 1)'`

I can successfully connect to the same DB via pgadmin and psql console with SSL certificates from my local machine(windows). But I need to do it through my application. Please help me to overcome this as it is showing as a high-security risk factor in the GCP Security Command Center.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible problems:

**ITEM 1:**

You have **'sslmode' => 'require'**. This means that the server certificate is validated against the CA. For Google Cloud SQL, the server's certificate contains the name of the Cloud SQL instance which does not match the hostname.

Change the value to **allow**. Google Cloud SQL will enforce client certificates. The PostgresQL client will not validate the server's certificate which will fail if validated.

**ITEM 2:**

The certificates are invalid. Open each one in a text editor and verify that they are text files with proper headers:

client_cert.pem: **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**
client_key.pem: **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**
server-ca.pem:  **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**

You can also use **openssl** to verify the files.

Comment: I checked the headers of them and all are ok. When I change the ssl mode as
'sslmode' => 'allow', I am getting different error
'connection to server at 10.112.***.*, port 5432 failed: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "10.156.*.*", user "***", database "****", SSL off connection to server at "10.112.***.*, port 5432 failed: SSL error: certificate verify failed'

Comment: @user3683222 - which version of Laravel?

Comment: It is laravel 8.

Comment: Finally I was able to fix this by using cloud auth proxy. Installed the cluoud proxy via docker and run '/var/www/html/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=your connection instance:datbase connection=tcp:127.0.0.1:5432' in the supervisor conf.

Answer (score 0):

On a slightly different method of accessing SSL enabled Postgres instance on Google Cloud SQL (using DBeaver), i had faced similar issue, here is what i have done.

1. ssl -> true
2. sslkey -> Provide Client Key file.
3. sslcert -> Provide Client Certificate.
4. sslfactory -> org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory.
5. sslmode -> verifiy-ca

Comment: How does your answer solve a `Laravel` problem? Did you mean to post this answer on a different question?

Comment: @JohnHanley: I think Laravel problem will be solved by the same settings used for DBeaver viz. 'sslmode' = 'prefer','sslcert'='cert_file','sslkey' = 'key_file' and 'sslfactory='org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory'. Secondly since the error is generic and would be thrown when invoked by any jdbc client, i thought of explaining my use case as well, in fact thats how i reached this post.

Comment: I have modified my answer and posted my DBeaver configuration issues and answers in a new thread. @JohnHanley