# How to connect to Postgres instance (managed service) running on SSL enabled Google Cloud Service using DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When provided with server certificate, client certificate and client key
Getting error `The hostname 33.333.333.33 could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.`

Answer (score 2):

I have faced couple of issues with accessing SSL enabled Postgres managed service on Google Cloud SQL and thought of sharing the consolidated view of the errors and its fixes.

Connecting to Postgres Managed instance on GCP Cloud SQL Service using DBeaver.

1. Add your IP to authorized network from GCP Cloud SQL Connections -> Networking tab. [Issue : Connection timed out error, [Reference](https://bobcares.com/blog/google-cloud-sql-connection-timeout) ]
2. Download Client Certificate and Client Key from GCP Cloud SQL Connections -> Create Client Certificate.
3. Client-key.pem file has to be converted to DER format with nocrypt. https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/8368. By deafult Google Cloud SQL will provide pem file format. [Error: Could not read SSL Key file key.pem extra data given to DerValue constructor]

   `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -nocrypt -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pk8`
4. From DBeaver Connection Configuration Screen, goto SSL Tab and provide **client key in DER format**, provide **client cert**, **sslMode = verifiy-ca** and SSL Factory to **org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70427552/6514559) is the reason why we cant verify the server certificate. [Error: the hostname could not be verified by hostnameverifier pgjdbchostnameverifier.]

[image: DBeaver Connection Configuration]

Comment: You can also use the Cloud SQL Java Connector and it will manage the certs for you so that you don't need to download any of them manually. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory